# R Temporarily write csv files during loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, export

I have a loop which downloads data from urls. Now I would like that for every x iterations, the information so far gets written away.

As such I have the following code:

```
    baseurl <- "http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Address.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=010"
    pages3 <- list()

for(i in 1:99999){


if(i < 10){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,"00000",i), flatten=TRUE)
  }
  if(i < 100 & i >= 10){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,"0000",i), flatten=TRUE)
  }
  if(i < 1000 & i >= 100){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,"000",i), flatten=TRUE) 
  }

  if(i < 10000 & i >= 1000){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,"00",i), flatten=TRUE)
  }  
  if(i < 100000 & i >= 10000){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,"0",i), flatten=TRUE) 
  }
  if(i < 1000000 & i >= 100000){
    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,i), flatten=TRUE) 
  }




    mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,i), flatten=TRUE) 

    pages3[[i]] <- mydata$resultatenHR
    options(timeout = 4000000)
    if(i %% 100 == 0){Sys.sleep(5)}
    if(i %% 1000 == 0){
      final_df<-do.call(rbind,pages3)
      final<- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), final_df)
      mytime <- format(Sys.time(), "%b_%d_%H_%M_%S_%Y")
      myfile <- file.path(R(), paste0(mytime, "_", i, ".csv"))
      write.csv2(final, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
                 quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
      }
  }

  }
}
```

However, nothing gets saved in the meantime? Where did I go wrong with the code? Thank you for your insights.

Comment: What does the function R() do?

Comment: i hope its not a function because then i made a mistake... Its meant to be the path to write to, i.e. c:\R\ .....

Comment: I tried replaying in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is probably in:

`myfile <- file.path(R(), paste0(mytime, "_", i, ".csv"))`

As R thinks `R()` is a function.

```
Error in R() : could not find function "R"
```

You can change it to `getwd()` if you want (don't forget to set working directory first `setwd()`) or specify a different path .

In addition, here: `write.csv2(final, file = myfile, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)`, your forgot to write `paste()`, and for convince you can delete the default arguments you used.

```
write.csv2(final, file = paste(myfile, sep = "" ))
```

#Edit

This is probably not the most efficient way but it will probably do the trick. 
The main issue is that you append the pages3 list object/csv file by the url index. If you'd create a new index for pages3, you can reset it every i urls.

```
setwd("Your working directory path")

baseurl <- "http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Address.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=010"
pages3 <- list()

#Counter for the url loop
i <- 1
#Counter for the appended csv file/ list object pages3
k <- 1

for(i in 1:99999){

  #Read JSON file by i index
  mydata <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,i), flatten=TRUE) 

  #Appending to the Pages3 list object by k index
  pages3[[k]] <- mydata$resultatenHR
  # Increasing the k counter 
  k <- k + 1

  options(timeout = 4000000)
  if(i %% 100 == 0) {Sys.sleep(5)}
  if(i %% 1000 == 0) {
    final_df <- do.call(rbind, pages3)
    final <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), final_df)
    mytime <- format(Sys.time(), "%b_%d_%H_%M_%S_%Y")
    myfile <- file.path(getwd(), paste0(mytime, "_", i, ".csv"))
    write.csv2(final, file = paste(myfile, sep = "" ))
    #Resetting the pages3 list object
    pages3 <- NULL
    #Resting the k index counter
    k <- 1
  }

}
```

However, depending on your computer/the size of the files you try to import, maybe it would be more efficient to save and split to different csv files when you finished imported all the urls.

Comment: Thanks, it worked partly, so I am getting there...R now makes every x (2000 in my case) iterations a new csv file. However, R is adding it all up, so file 1: 2000 rows, file 2: 4000 rows, etc. However, I would like to have file 1: 2000 rows, file 2: 2000 rows, etc, etc.. You know of any addition?

Comment: Thanks, I am testing it now. The reason I am doing the per 2000 split is because otherwise the file gets too large. Depending on the series, the pages list contains >100000 elements, and >100 mb. Hence the split because then it is manageable.I once let it run without splitting the files, and the pages list got over 25gb, and then computer / R crashed....

Comment: It's because the url doesn't work well. For example, when i=200 the url will be http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Address.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=010200, which leads you to an empty page.

Comment: I know, thats why I added additional if statements, see my addition in begin post..... Any further suggestions?